# Angular ViewContainerRef.createComponent breaks when called second time

Tags: angular

I have my app devided as the following, Header, Context, and Content.

I need to be able to inject dynamically into the Context Component(viewContainerRef) other components depending on the route and other factors.

For this I developed:

This will work as my ViewContainerRef and I inject here the ContextService which shall be used when we need to change the current context component being displayed.

```
export class ContextComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("contextComponent", {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private contextService: ContextService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.contextService.setViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
    }
}
```

The ContextService itselft

```
export class ContextService {
    private component!:        ComponentRef<any>;
    private viewContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;

    public setViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef): void {
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }

    public setComponent<T>(component: Type<T>): ComponentRef<T> {
        this.viewContainerRef.clear();
        this.component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent<T>(component);
        return this.component;
    }

    public instance<T>(): T {
        return (this.component as ComponentRef<T>).instance;
    }
}
```

Now I the ideia is use this service like

```
 setupContext(): void {
        this.context.setComponent(ClientPersonEditContextComponent);
        this.context.instance<ClientPersonEditContextComponent>().clientName.set(this.client.firstName + " " + this.client.lastName);
    }
```

This works only the first time, after that the view is loaded into the DOM but the functionality simply breaks. No console log error.

[image: First time app loads works fine]

[image: Second time app breaks]

Comment: You'll most likely need to provide a stackblitz, because the problem is not reproducible as described. One obvious error though: accessing `ViewChild` in `ngOnInit` is not guaranteed to work at all.

Comment: Yes I maybe have. The element is present on ngOnInit and as I said it works as expected when I inject the first context component, then when some time later I try to inject other component into the context it breaks. I understand its not an easy problem to visualise. Now I dont have the time but when I do I will create an working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to make it work

I need to have in the service a reference of ChangeDetectorRef to trigger it manually.
So the implementation is now as the following:

ContextComponent (ViewContainerRef)

```
export class ContextComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("contextComponent", {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private contextService: ContextService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.contextService.setCdr(this.changeDetectorRef);
        this.contextService.setViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
    }
}
```

And the service to manage the context

```
export class ContextService {
    private component!:         ComponentRef<any>;
    private viewContainerRef!:  ViewContainerRef;
    private changeDetectorRef!: ChangeDetectorRef;

    public setCdr(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef): void {
        this.changeDetectorRef = changeDetectorRef;
    }
    public setViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef): void {
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }

    public setComponent<T>(component: Type<T>): ComponentRef<T> {
        this.viewContainerRef.clear();
        this.component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent<T>(component);
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        return this.component;
    }

    public instance<T>(): T {
        return (this.component as ComponentRef<T>).instance;
    }
}
```